# Isn't PHP multithreaded?

Tags: php, multithreading, blocking

The scenario is as follows:

Frontend (written in React) makes a request to my api gateway which forwards the request to the related service (another api call).
User1 clicks a button B which is handled by MyController method myMethod in my API gateway and then another user, user2 clicks the same button B which is handled by the same controller and the same method. (I've tested that by opening two separate browsers for each user).

User 2 clicks the button right after user 1 clicks it.
I noticed that if for user1 the execution takes say 15 seconds to complete, the execution for user 2 is blocked and it runs after execution for user 1 completes. I would not expect this to happen, it is like both requests are served by the same thread, and the execution is blocked.

And to be more precise that blocking method (in my API gateway) it makes a Http async request to an API. I thought the second call from user 2 will run in a different thread and it would return before user1 finishes!

The way I tested it after I noticed that it is blocking is that for the first user1 I've made the code so that it makes an API call and the method that serves it has a delay (using sleep()):

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('testCallSlow', function (){
    sleep(15);
    return json_encode('some result for user 1');
});
```

and then another endpoint for user 2:

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('testCall', function (){  
    return json_encode('some result for user 2');
});
```

Is this the right behavior? Will it be different when deployed on a real server?

I was wandering whether on a real server threading will be handled differently.

I thought to ask before I go with RabbitMQ. Has anyone faced the same issue?

My development environment is Xamp, Apache, and everything is hosted through apache (virtualhost) I am NOT using `php artisan serve` (I did initially and I thought that may be the problem since local development server might well be a simplified version running on a single thread).

frontEnd calls API gateway on this method (both users):

```
public function userDetails(Request $request)
{
    // check user has no permission to proceed, if not return 403
    if (!$this->permissionService->userCanAccess(auth()->user(), Microservice::RESCOM_MSERVICE_ID))
    {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'user does not have permission to access the requested resource.'])->setStatusCode(403);
    }
$rescom_token = $this->getSessionToken(); // writes token to session the 1st time, any susequent calls only read.

    // proceed with call to rescom api
    $url = 'http://rescom.io/api/testCall';

    // This -if is only put here for testing two different users, 
   // each user's request is forwarded to different endpoints (see 
    // actual end points above)
    if (auth()->user()->id == 2)
    {
        $url = 'http://rescom.io/api/testCallSlow';
    }

    try
    {
        $body = '';
        $promise = Http::withToken($rescom_token)->async()->get($url)->then(function($response) use (& $body)
        {
            $body = $response->body();
        });

        $promise->wait();

        return $body;
    }
    catch (\Exception $e)
    {
        return \response()->json($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, Apache is a real server. You say: _"I've tested that by opening two separate browsers for each user"_. How exactly did you do that? One browser is Chrome and the other Safari or Firefox? Still on the same computer?

Comment: `Isn't PHP multithreaded?` No, PHP is not multithreaded.

Comment: `it is like both requests are served by the same thread, and the execution is blocked.` this could be for multiple reasons. One (and very hard to miss) is not calling `session_write_close()`: `[...] but as session data is locked to prevent concurrent writes only one script may operate on a session at any time. `

Comment: Yes, one was Chrome and the other one was Edge. And yes, still on the same computer. I know apache is areal server, though I don't know if its configuration differs when running on a real server and I need to do something about it in its mpm.conf...

Comment: If you use two different browser then you will have two different PHP sessions, so it shouldn't be the session that is blocking. It could simply be what you do in those 15 seconds that causes the block. For instance a database table may be blocked by a query?

Comment: @KIKO Software At the service end (not the Gateway which serves the user requests) I do a sleep() for the purpose of mimicking a delay. There is no database access involved. Even for the real scenario end user clicks a button, frontend (React app) makes an API request to my API Gateway, the method in the API Gateway makes a call to another API exposed by a Laravel app. (laravel which acts as a wrapper for a legacy Api). At the end of the day, all processes only read stuff...

Comment: There's a lot going on. Too much to be able to tell what causes the blocking. If you really want to know you have to simplify the problem. As far as I know Apache is quite happy to take many concurrent request and delegate them to instances of PHP. These should run in parallel (which is not the same as "multithreading" inside PHP).

Comment: ...but anyway, if two requests from different users hit the same Controller and the same method aren't these run in different threads within the same process (so they share process resources)? If so, I understand that if a resource is locked by the first thread the second cannot execute until the lock is released. Session is the common resource in my case, though I only write to it the very first time each user hits this method (I am saving the sanctum token used between services to communicate), all subsequent calls do not write, but only read token from current user session since it exists.

Comment: Actually I will remove session access altogether to see if this is the problem...
...just tried it, didn't solve anything...

Comment: Session access will only be a problem if it is the **same session**. But your approach is correct. Try out several things. Simplify, and isolate. The most basic PHP page would be one with only a `sleep()` in it. Does that still block? Let me try that myself, it's easy to do.

Comment: OK, tested it, and having only a `sleep()` in a PHP file doesn't block. So if I do `sleep(15);` and run two pages, in the same browser, shortly after each other, then they finish shortly after each other.

Comment: @KIKO Software I have it very simple:
The API which is last in the chain serves the calls by the closure in the route definition, check my initial post, only a sleep is in there... 
Now, the method that forwards the call (i.e. the method in the API gateway only makes an async call. check my initial post in a few minutes, I will edit to add the actual code.

Comment: It's not that, but it is the Http:get(), other code in there is not blocking, so if i remove the http get() it is not blocking

Comment: @KIKO Software
Thanx for your time, you helped me solve it.
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/296743/non-blocking-http-request-with-guzzle

This article offers a solution to the problem of blocking http requests even if they are asynchronous. Need to use rabbitMQ which handles all that.

Comment: Thank you, but you really solve this problem by yourself.

Comment: You intrigued my thought process :)

Comment: Haha, Ok. Well, it clearly helped. 

Comment: @KIKOSoftware You are right. I was under the impression that all sessions created by PHP were under the same lock, not that that would make any sense, but PHP (for me) is a pretty senseless language.

Comment: Just to be complete, I'm saying this because of PHP's limited and arbitrary API "convention" (I know, for some this is an old argument), PHP has its purpose but it's not known for being particularly smart or well thought through.

Comment: @marco-a No language is perfect. PHP works just fine for what I do with it. I don't like Javascript all that much with its obscure syntax and you never know whether people are talking about it server side or client side.